# How do I access all but the first column of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some trouble with sklearn.cluster.

I`ve prepeared my data to clustering and have few columns with float-type data.

I`ve chek twice, the columns dtype is float64 but when i tried to

```
df['cluster'] = cluster.fit_predict([df.columns[1:])
```

I see:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: column_name_1
```

Last Traceback look like

```
       ...
   -> return self.fit(X).lables
       ...
   -> X = Self._check_fit_data(X)
       ...
   -> X = check_array(X, accept_sparce='csr', dtype = [np.float, np.float32])
       ...
   -> array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
```

I tried to convert float to string and back, but it does not work.
What should i try to fix this problem?
P.S. I use Python 2.7.

Comment: On a different note, I think it should be "self.fit(X).labels" instead of "self.fit(X).lables"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fit the column names.

```
df['cluster'] = cluster.fit_predict([df.columns[1:])
```

It should be

```
df['cluster'] = cluster.fit_predict(df.loc[:,1:])
```

Comment: `df[df.columns[1:]]`* and indexing on the columns is not necessary, they could just use `iloc`.